# How can I create many to many between IdentityUser and IdentityRole?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Microsoft Identity, I need to create many to many relation with `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`. I am adding property as `public virtual ICollection<Role> IdentityRoles { get; set; }` to `IdentityUser` class and `public virtual ICollection<User> IdentityUsers { get; set; }` to `IdentityRole` but migration add a table that named `RoleUsers`.

I want to use existing `UserRoles` table for many to many relation.

How can I create?

Comment: Are you sure you need a many-to-many relation? Or are you only interested in: 1. the roles linked to a user and 2. all users linked to a role?

Comment: The relationship is already many to many out of the box (thus the existing junction table).

Comment: I am sure I need many to many relation. There is a relation but IdentityRole Users property returns ICollection<UserRole> and IdentityUser Roles property return ICollection<UserRole>. I want to call all roles from IdentityUser and all users from IdentityRole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users and Roles are already many to many.

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{     
    var usersAndTheirRoles = context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList();
    var rolesAndTheirUsers = context.Roles.Include(u => u.Users).ToList();
}
```

or are you looking to do something different?

EDIT: You can get IdentityRoles from the role manager:

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

foreach (var iur in users.First().Roles)
{
    var identityRole = roleManager.FindById(iur.RoleId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is not working. Because Roles in Users return type of IdentityUserRole.

Comment: Yeah, the design is not right, but you can get the info from a role manager or maybe with a JOIN back to roles table.